# How do I change the selection of a combo box mid program?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a combo box on a swing panel. I set the index to the default index, but based on the input of a text box I want to change the combo box selection. So if the user enters 2 I want it to select the second option in the combo box.

Does anyone know what line I would need for this? I tried

```
combobox.setSelectedIndex(2);
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. So all you need is a JFrame with your combo box, text field and ActionListener. Once you get this working, then you fix your real application.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [JComboBox docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setSelectedIndex(int)), indices are 0-based, so if you wanted to set the second item, that would be index 1.

So, assuming you've already done some validation to ensure the entered number is in the range [1, numOptions] then you can safely call:

```
combobox.setSelectedIndex(enteredNumber - 1);
```

Something like:

```
// Assume this is initialized by getting from edit text field where
// the entered number is a human-understandable index starting with 1.
int enteredNumber;
if (enteredNumber > 0 && enteredNumber <= combobox.getItemCount()) {
    combobox.setSelectedIndex(enteredNumber - 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't change the selection of the combobox, I have tried just hard programming it with a number and it still doesn't change

Comment: What happens if you call combobox.repaint() immediately after your call to setSelectedIndex?  Are you sure you are making the call to setSelectedIndex from the UI thread?